# There is no activity since a to b or No activity since a to b?

Tags: grammaticality, there-is, non-native-english

It's used in the app's interface.

I wonder if omitting there is/there are is not a grammatical mistake and sounds native (I'm not a native speaker).

So, which do you think will sound better in a web app?

**There is no activity since a to b**

**No activity since a to b**

Comment: Leaving out _there is_ does not make the sentence less understandable, and is generally just fine. _However_, I do not understand what you mean with _since a to b_ in either version of your sentence. Do you mean _**from** (moment) a to (moment) b_?

Comment: @oerkelens I mean date ranges. e.g.: No activity since 05-04-16 to 05-04-17

Comment: You cannot use _since_ like that. You can say _No activity since 05-04-16_ or you can say _no activity from 05-04-16 to 05-04-17_. _Since 05-04-16_ means the same as _between 05-04-16 and now_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since* is not the correct word here. You should use *from* or *between*, and you should use the past tense if *b* occurred before now.

Depending on your intended meaning, the following work:

- "There is/was no activity between *A* and *B*."
- "There is/was no activity from *A* to *B*."

Real world examples of "there is *A* from *B* to *C*":

- ["There is *a $1 surcharge* from *4pm* to *8pm* on weekdays"](http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/passenger/taxicab_rate.shtml)
- ["There is *a causal link* from *inequality* to *growth*"](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/sdn/2014/sdn1402.pdf)

Also, "no activity since a to b" by itself is just a sentence fragment (there is no verb there).

Comment: Thanks. In my case, the first date always preseeds the second one. I would like to emphasize that it's the app's interface. So, do you think the full sentence is still better than the part? more context: this message appears several times, for example you choose a date range and want to see if you received messages during that time. so instead of list with messages you receive empty list that says no activity from yesterday to today. (yesterday and today being something you chose to sort by)

Comment: So *B* always precedes *now*. It wouldn't be unusual to use the sentence fragment especially if the app doesn't usually use complete sentences but instead relies mostly on symbols.